# How to assign to variables in django based on user_authentication?

Tags: django, authentication

I want to show different menus to authorized and unauthorized user.Following is the code snippet for public access:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated():
    (menu_c,menu_t) = mn_view.rightMenuPublic(request)
    print "public"

#only for authenticated user:
else:
    (menu_c,menu_t) = mn_view.rightMenuRestricted(request)
    print "private"
```

but only public menu is what I'm getting

Comment: I hate to ask the obvious here, but have you checked to see if, in fact, the user is not authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

The code you quoted is in view, right? If so, it really should work.

The only thing I can think of is maybe your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py` got changed somehow. You should have `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` there, and probably `Session` and `Common` as well. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/middleware/